# How to run Google Analytics in Next JS without crippling the performance?

Tags: performance, next.js, google-analytics, partytown

I finished building a `Next JS` website and as a finishing touch, I added `Google Analytics`.

But when I added `Google Analytics` my page performance dropped from 96 to 78.

TBT jumps from 210ms to 810ms, and sometimes the LCP and SI also suffer.

After researching how to fix my performance issue I found the `Partytown Library`

I tried to use the `Partytown Library` to send the Google Analytics script to a web worker, but I can't figure out how it works.

This is how I tried to use the Partytown library:

```
import Header from "@/components/universal/Heder/Header";
import "./globals.css";
import StyledComponentsRegistry from "../lib/registry";
import Footer from "@/components/universal/Footer/Footer";
import ScrollToTopButton from "@/components/universal/ScrollButton/ScrollToTopButton";
export const metadata = {
    title: "Visit Drežnica | Rent a Room",
    description:
        "Drežnica near Mostart. Experience serene mountains, a picturesque river, and warm hospitality. Perfect for nature lovers seeking a peaceful getaway.",
};
import Head from "next/head";
import { Partytown } from "@builder.io/partytown";

export default function RootLayout({ children }) {
    return (
        <html lang="en" suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
            <StyledComponentsRegistry>
                <Head>
                    <title>My App</title>
                    <Partytown debug={true} forward={["dataLayer.push"]} />
                    <script
                        src="https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtag/js?id=###########"
                        type="text/partytown"
                        async
                    />
                    <script type="text/partytown">
                        {`
                        window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
                        function gtag(){dataLayer.push(arguments);}
                        gtag('js', new Date());
                        gtag('config', '###########');
                    `}
                    </script>
                </Head>
                <body suppressHydrationWarning={true}>
                    <header>
                        <Header />
                    </header>
                    {children}
                    <ScrollToTopButton />
                    <footer>
                        <Footer />
                    </footer>
                </body>
            </StyledComponentsRegistry>
        </html>
    );
}
```

This is my nextjs.config:

```
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
    compiler: {
        styledComponents: true,
    },
    experimental: {
        nextScriptWorkers: true,
    },
};

export default nextConfig;
```

This is just one of the ways I tried to use the Partytown Library, I tried a bunch but I couldn't figure out how it works.

I tried for 4 days straight to find a solution but didn't find anything useful.

Let me know if you have any clue on how to set up Partytown or use Google Analytics.

Comment: Do you have any caching issues with builder.io and next.js? We have a couple of pages not busting cache after an update. Sometimes it shows the correct content, sometimes is shows old content, and sometimes it 404s.

Comment: Have you found any solution for this @Ermin? I'm also using Nextjs 14. I only tried @next/third-parties/google, but it makes the page slow, too (from 92 to 61).

Answer (score 0):

Next.js has optimized a couple of Google packages like Tag Manager and Analytics to solve issues similar to yours via the [@next/third-parties](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@next/third-parties) package.

You can see the official [Next.js implementation docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/optimizing/third-party-libraries)

Analytics - root layout.tsx

```js
import { GoogleAnalytics } from '@next/third-parties/google'
     
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
      <GoogleAnalytics gaId="G-XYZ" />
    </html>
   )
}
```

Tag manager - root layout.tsx

```js
import { GoogleTagManager } from '@next/third-parties/google'
 
export default function RootLayout({ children }: { children: React.ReactNode }) {
  return (
    <html lang="en">
      <body>{children}</body>
      <GoogleTagManager gtmId="GTM-XYZ" />
    </html>
  )
}
```

Comment: Will this work with the pages directory too?